# How to get original (non-edited) rows in SM30 events?

Tags: events, abap

I need to get the view data and do some validations about "whether the DB data got updated by others during my time of editing.". Since the generated program already reads the data from DB during read function, I did not want to write a select query to do the same.

I am aware that `TOTAL[]` and `EXTRACT[]` holds only the edited data. Is there a structure that holds data from the initialization time?

I tried searching through existing runtime variants but did not find any? Is there a way to capture the values in an already existing runtime structure?

Comment: No idea why you need to save TOTAL but there are many user exits ("events") and you can save `TOTAL` at startup. See the [event AA for instance](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=Event%20AA%3A%20Instead%20of%20the%20Standard%20Data%20Read%20Routine).

Comment: Yes, initially I was checking AA but this is for a complete revamp. My check is just to read the existing data on runtime. but figured out another event for it. Thanks.

Comment: In the solution you proposed, i.e. using the event `06`, it's up to the user to click the function "Get Original" (which is a kind of undo to restore one or more selected lines as they are in the database) to trigger the code to "hold data from the initialization time". It's unclear in your question why the user needs to click "Get Original" to "hold data". I guess you'd better add a new menu option or button, to trigger a new feature.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood `event 06`. I could see the event getting triggered even without pressing "Get Original". So I was planning to utilize it.

Comment: My requirement is simple. I need to get the view data and do some validations about "whether the DB data got updated by others during my time of editing.". Since the generated program already reads the data from DB during read function, I did not want to write a select query to do the same.

Comment: I don't know how it's possible to trigger the event `06` without pressing the button "Get Original" (tooltip "Undo Changes"/Ctrl+F2), the only possibility I can think of is a bug in your software version. Your issue is not about the maintenance dialog, it's about "data got updated by others during my time", it should be impossible because there is a SAP lock via the lock object `E_TABLEE`, 2 persons should not be able to maintain at the same time by using the dialog. Any custom program should check the SAP lock before updating the table.

Comment: Yes you’re absolutely right about how lock object works. It’s just that the current requirement doesn’t require the working of a standard lock and place custom code for the validation. You know how business requirements are right! 

It’s part of a huge customisation and did not want to delve deep into the misc details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, there is no global variable that holds the initial display data.

`AA` event is more about complete revamp of the select logic. So this works if we are to change the current logic before display.

`Event 06: After completely performing the function 'Get original'` is more apt in my case since I just need to read the data. It triggers right after the program fetches initial values.